# Optimization Tips

Tags: c, optimization

```
int *s;
allocate memory for s[100];
void func (int *a, int *b)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        s[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
    }
}
```

Assume that this particular code snippet is being called 1000 times, and this is the most time consuming operation in my code. Also assume that addresses of a and b is changed every time. 's' is a global variable which is updated with different sets of values of a & b.

As far as I assume, the main performance bottleneck would be memory access, because the only other operation is XOR, which is very trivial.

Would you please suggest how can I optimize my code in the best possible way?

the question I really wanted to ask, but I think it didn't get properly conveyed is, let for example this for loop contains 10 such XOR operations, the loop count is 100 and the function is called 1000 times, the point is high memory access..If the code is to be executed on a single core machine, what are scopes for improvement?

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is not due to allocating memory?  malloc involves periodic calls to expensive memory allocation code in the OS.  example: in unix that call is brk().

Comment: Does this function need to be thread-safe?

Comment: What is `s`? Why is it local? The function doesn't really do anything if it just fills up a local array, so the best possible way to optimise it would be to remove it completely. Why is your function `int` if it doesn't return anything? What are you using this for? You need to give us a lot more information.

Comment: this function is strange. it computes `s` which is promptly discarded and the allocated memory leaked. hence, the best possible optimization is probably `int func(int *a, int *b) { (void)a; (void)b; }`

Comment: please see the edited version of the question. Initially it had some mistakes...

Comment: What platform are you on? Compiler + CPU?

Comment: Did you profile your application and this code? Before doing optimizations always and always profile. Everything else is since fiction

Comment: @RED: The OP did say that this is the most time-consuming operation. What more do you want?

Comment: I am using linux with gcc 4.4.3, I profiled and found out this is the most time consuming operation. That's is why I asked to know what people to in this circumstances?

Comment: You must provide more information about the calling function. Are some of the a and b arrays duplicates? When it comes to memory bottlenecks you really need to consider the whole access pattern, not just a little 100 element loop. Reordering the memory access at a slightly higher level can have a dramatic effect on performance depending what is going on.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil (Donald Knuth). Always make sure, where the bottleneck is, before you profile. Its so easy to just miss the real bottleneck.

Answer (score 9):

I've tested proposed solutions, and other two. I was not able to test onemasse' proposal as the result saved to s[] was not correct. I was not able to fix it too. I had to do some changes on moonshadow code. The measurement unit is clock cycles, so lower is better.

**Original code:**

```
#define MAX 100
void inline STACKO ( struct timespec *ts, struct timespec *te ){

    int i, *s, *a, *b;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; ++i){
        s = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int)); ++s;
        a = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int)); ++a;
        b = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int)); ++b;
    }

    srand ( 1024 );
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; ++i){
        a[i] = ( rand() % 2 );
        b[i] = ( rand() % 2 );
    }

    rdtscb_getticks ( ts ); /* start measurement */

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        s[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];

    rdtscb_getticks ( te ); /* end measurement */

/*
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
        printf("%d", s[i]);
    printf("\n");
*/
}
```

**New proposal 1: register int**

From:

```
int i, *s, *a, *b;
```

To:

```
register int i, *s, *a, *b;
```

**New proposal 2: No array notation**

```
s_end = &s[MAX];
for (s_ptr = &s[0], a_ptr = &a[0], b_ptr = &b[0]; \
   s_ptr < s_end; \
   ++s_ptr, ++a_ptr, ++b_ptr){
    *s_ptr = *a_ptr ^ *b_ptr;
}
```

**moonshadow proposed optimization:**

```
s_ptr = &s[0];
a_ptr = &a[0];
b_ptr = &b[0];

for (i = 0; i < (MAX/4); i++){

    s_ptr[0] = a_ptr[0] ^ b_ptr[0];
    s_ptr[1] = a_ptr[1] ^ b_ptr[1];
    s_ptr[2] = a_ptr[2] ^ b_ptr[2];
    s_ptr[3] = a_ptr[3] ^ b_ptr[3];
    s_ptr+=4; a_ptr+=4; b_ptr+=4;
}
```

**moonshadow proposed optimization + register int:**

From:

```
int i, *s, ...
```

To:

```
register int i, *s, ...
```

**Christoffer proposed optimization:**

```
#pragma omp for
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    s[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
}
```

## Results:

[image: Performance graph]

```
Original Code   1036.727264
New Proposal 1  611.147928
New proposal 2  450.788845
moonshadow      713.3845
moonshadow2     452.481192
Christoffer     1054.321943
```

There is other simple way of optimizing the resulting binary. Passing -O2 to gcc tells that you want optimization. To know exactly what -O2 does, refer to gcc man page.

After enabling -O2:
[image: Performance graph]

```
Original Code   464.233031
New Proposal 1  452.620255
New proposal 2  454.519383
moonshadow      428.651083
moonshadow2     419.317444
Christoffer     452.079057
```

Source codes available at: http://goo.gl/ud52m

Answer (score 5):

Don't use the loop variable to index.
Unroll the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < (100/4); i++)
{
  s[0] = a[0] ^ b[0];
  s[1] = a[1] ^ b[1];
  s[2] = a[2] ^ b[2];
  s[3] = a[3] ^ b[3];
  s+=4; a+=4; b+=4;
}
```

Work out how to perform SIMD XOR on your platform.

Performing these XORs as an explicit step is potentially more expensive than doing them as part of another calculation: you're having to read from a and b and store the result in s - if s is read again for more calculation, you'd save a read and a write per iteration, and all the function call and loop overhead, by doing the XOR there instead; likewise, if a and b are outputs of some other functions, you do better by performing the XOR at the end of one of those functions.

Comment: And you think the compiler cannot do that itself, given the constant upper bound?! It will, *and* it will insert the appropriate SIMD instructions (if they happen to be beneficial here, which is probably the case).

Comment: @Konrad: I spend all day looking at disassembled compiler output. Much of the time, on all three platforms we support, the compilers fail to do this sort of thing well or at all. I have *never* seen the compiler produce sensible SIMD code in the absence of explicit hints (i.e. using the platform's SIMD types and intrinsics).

Comment: @moonshadow: this may seem like a stupid question, but did you enable optimizations (-O3)? SIMD instructions are inserted all the time by compilers. Now you’ve tickled my interest and I’d love to actually test this out – but unfortunately I’ve got to run. Perhaps another time … :-(

Comment: @Konrad: haha. In theory, one of our platforms even supports GCC autovectorization (http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html). In practice, I'm only filing a bug report against the compiler once a month or so now so I guess things are improving a little. Whatever happened to the Octopiler?

Comment: Automatic vectorization isn't that easy. The compiler needs needs to be able to proof that a, b and s are divisible by 16 and if not insert appropriate paddings, which add overhead. This overhead may actually worsen the performance of code, which I noticed when -fno-tree-vectorize increased performance on some critical loops.

Comment: @Konrad: -O3 is not enough.  GCC, for example, will not unroll loops unless you explicitly use `-funroll-loops`, and will not attempt to use SIMD instructions unless you use `-march=$SOMETHING` to specify that the code is to be run on a processor that supports them.

Comment: @Porculus: you’re right about `-funroll-loops`, you’re wrong about `-march`. `-O3` is actually sufficient to enable vectorization using SIMD on a processor that supports it (tested on OS X, GCC 4.5).

Comment: @drhirsch: Interesting. I didn’t think that padding would impact performance that much but I can see why that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *s;
allocate memory for s[100];
void func (int *a, int *b)
{
    int i;

    #pragma omp for
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        s[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
    }
}
```

Of course, for only a hundred elements you might not see any particular improvement :-)

Comment: Even inserting the “parallel” you forgot, this will actually be much *slower* for a mere 100 numbers.

Comment: Ah, you're quite right Kondrad. I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: It could be appropriate at the next higher level which calls this function 1000 times.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here. If this is a cache issue you could try this:

```
int *s;
allocate memory for s[100];
void func (int *a, int *b)
{
    int i;

    memcpy( s, a, 100 );

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        s[i] = s[i] ^ b[i];
    }
}
```

The memcpy, although it's a function call will often be inlined by the compiler if the size argument is a constant. Loop unrolling will probably not help here as it can be done automatically by the compiler. But you shouldn't take my word for it, verify on your platform.